# Is it possible to generate means and standard deviations for two groups based on a Cohen's d?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, effect-size

**Is it possible to generate means and standard deviation for two groups from a Cohen's d effect size?**

Even if the means and standard deviations are trivial/meaningless values, I would like to keep the same effect size.

The formula for Cohen's d is as follows:

```
d = (mean(x1) - mean(x2))  / (pooled sd of x1 and x2)
```

Comment: Short answer is no. The measure is based on a difference and then a ratio. Different differences and/or ratios are compatible with the same value of d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note that I'm not quite clear what the motivation is for your problem.*

But if you define Cohen's d as

$$d = \frac{{\bar x_1} - {\bar x_2}}{s_{\rm{pooled}}}$$

then using basic algebra you can obtain $\bar{x}_1$ if you know $\bar{x}_2$ and $s_{\rm{pooled}}$:

$${\bar x_1} = {\bar x_2} + d \times s_{\rm{pooled}}$$

or similarly you can obtain $\bar{x}_2$ if you know $\bar{x}_1$ and $s_{\rm{pooled}}$:

$${\bar x_2} = {\bar x_1} - d \times s_{\rm{pooled}}$$

Similarly you could use algebra to find $s_1$ if you knew $n_1$, $n_2$, $d$ and $s_2$ but I can't imagine a situation where you would have all that information and not also have $s_1$.